# Porque é que o EF Core não carrega as informações das Tabelas relacionadas?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Vou começar por postar os meus modelos de dados

```
public class Anuncio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TipoAnuncio TipoAnuncio { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Aprovado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Telefone { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Pais Pais { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Localidade Localidade { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}

public class TipoAnuncio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
public class TipoAnuncio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

> Quando consulto os dados na base de dados os dados existem o que
>   exclui a possibilidade do dado não existir mesmo na base de dados

**Onde existe problema?**
Quando consulto anuncio existem dados que não estão a vir e os dados são todos os que vêm por meios de outra tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como estou a tentar obter esses dados?**

```
    var anuncios = await _context.Anuncio.ToListAsync();
```

**Aqui estão dos dados na base de dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você relacionou corretamente, e mandar carregar por exemplo pelo método `Include` deveria aparecer os dados da relação. Agora como você não postou as relações fica complicado em dizer

Comment: Exatamente esse era o problema @VirgilioNovic não estava usando o método Include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta é simples:

Preciso de utilizar `Include` a todas as outras tabelas de dados.

```
var   anuncios = await _context.Anuncio.Include(x => x.Cor)
               .Include(x => x.Imagens)
               .Include(x => x.Localidade)
               .Include(x => x.Pais)
               .Include(x => x.Porte)
               .Include(x => x.Raca)
               .Include(x => x.Sexo)
               .Include(x => x.TipoAnimal)
               .Include(x => x.TipoAnuncio)
               .Include(x => x.User)
               .Include(x => x.Vacinado)
               .Include(x => x.Cor).ToListAsync();
```